# How do you subtract the average of a category, which is stored in another dataset for all categories and years, from a value in another dataset?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, match, subtraction

I have a Dataset of GDP Growth Rates for several industries from 2007 to 2020 for several countries. My goal is to subtract the average GDP growth in an industrial sector in a year from the GDP growth in an industrial sector in a year of a country.

[This is an extract of my original Dataset with GDP Growth Rates for respective industries and countries from 2007 - 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGAxe.png)

For the average growth rates, I created the following dataset using the following code.

Mean_Industry <- data.frame(GDP %>% group_by(Industry, Year) %>% summarize(Avg = mean(GrowthRate)))

[This is an extraction of the average growth rates for each industry and year across countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY4j2.png)

Now I want to create a New column in my original dataset with the difference of growth rate and average growth rate. The correct average growth rate for subtraction depends on the year and the industry. In each row, I need to check if the year and industry match with the dataset that contains the averages. Thus, the correct average can be selected and subtracted from the growth rate of the industry sector of a year and a country.

Can anyone help me program this in R-studio that the correct average growth rates are selected and subtracted from the growth rate of a country and sector?

Comment: Just a tip: you'll get better visibility and higher quality responses if you tag R and/or R-Studio

Comment: @RMADev don;t tag RStudio unless the question is specifically related to an issue with RStudio.

Comment: @Markus can you use the dput functions to create a minimial dataset?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.